# Specifying window.frame with postMessage

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I'm using postMessage to push the parent page css to the page within each iframe. The issue is that there may be more than 1 iframe already on the page before this code is applied. Therefore, how can I apply the postMessage specifically to the `id` of each frame, instead of having to manually enter `window.frames[0]` and `window.frames[1]`, where `[]` is adjusted based on the page.

**iframe**

```
<iframe id="frame1" style="width: 100%; height: 420px;" src="../syndicatedPlayer.html#videoUrl=http://video.mp4?" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe id="frame2" style="width: 100%; height: 420px;" src="../syndicatedPlayer.html#videoUrl=http://video.mp4?" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**postMessage()**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var getFontFamily = function() {
      var el = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
      var cs = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
      return cs.fontFamily;
  } 

    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var data = getFontFamily("h1");

    window.frames[0].postMessage(data, 'http://url.html');
    window.frames[1].postMessage(data, 'http://url.html');

    console.log('Message sent -->');
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `window===window.frames`, so you can just use window[0] to obtain the frame.

Said that, a way to obtain an iframe by its id is the following function:

```
function getFrameById(id) {
  for (var i=0;i<window.length;i++) {
    if (window[i].frameElement.id===id) return window[i];
  }
  return null;
}
```

Update: I've fixed and completed you fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9qtcmbnn/4/

Comment: Not exactly sure how to call the `getFrameById()` function here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/9qtcmbnn/

Comment: You need to create the iframes and set an id on them

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, as the `console.log('Message sent -->');` is not being hit, nor is it grabbing the frames correctly.

Comment: One of the issues with your update is that the tag that the script is grabbing the font from, won't always be the `h1` tag. This just needs to be able to apply to the frames with `id="frame1"` and `id="frame2"`.

Comment: I see the message in the console, and the alert is popped up by the iframe targeted.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify which iframe you will use by selecting it by id and then postmessage the data you want from it

you can use it as below

```html
<script>
        function test1() {       
 document.getElementById('idMyIframe1').contentWindow.postMessage("your message here", "*");
        }
         function test2() {       
 document.getElementById('idMyIframe2').contentWindow.postMessage("your message here", "*");
        }
    </script>
    <iframe id="idMyIframe1" onload="test1()" src="http://example.otherdomaintosenddatato.com"></iframe>
     <iframe id="idMyIframe2" onload="test2()" src="http://example.otherdomaintosenddatato.com"></iframe>
```